# Power Bi Desktop- Couldn't load the schema for the database model

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-datagateway

[Power BI desktop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVStu.jpg) Downloaded the Power BI desktop version.
Installed it.
And Opened it.
This message popped up.
"Couldn't load the schema for the database model"
"We couldn't retrieve the data model for this report. Please try again."
And also whenever I want to load Dataset from excel sheet this message popped up.

Comment: Please provide more details. The data source that you are using, any relevant details, etc. Screenshots are key.

Comment: Added screenshot.Data from excel sheet (.xlsx) format.

Answer (score 1):

This is being caused by x64 build of Power BI Desktop. I suggest you uninstall the current PowerBI Desktop and reinstall an older x64 build or latest x32 build.

I simply installed the latest x32 build and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot - Switching to x32 like Malik said worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer per se, but may help others when troubleshooting:

I've noticed that when using the latest (June 2022, v2.106.582.0) x64 version of the PowerBI desktop app in a Remote Desktop Services environment, where the session hosts are 20212R2, if the "Desktop Experience" windows feature is installed I get the error on launching the app, on Session Hosts without this feature installed, the app launches fine. (I don't have a PowerBI license or access to any datasources to test further, but the fact I'm not getting the error message on launch hopefully counts for something!)

Edit to add: Seems to be OK on Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error since yesterday (after updating to the newest Power BI version). In all datasets that I tried to open, it gave me this message. I tried complex ones with connections to various power bi online datasets and simple ones with only 1 web data source. When I tried to open the same datasets on a different machine I didn't get the errors.

I'm going to wipe PowerBI from all connections and reinstall it, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Try an older version. After many research on internet I found that to use power bi I had to use the older version. Its because the new update of power bi. Now it was removed from Windows 8 because it is not in the MS STORE. So, Do check with your System OS version and x64 or x32 version.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved in the latest (2.107.683.0, July 2022) x64 build, it loads without errors on Server 2012R2 (with and without the dekstop experience feature installed) as well as Server 2016